# How often should I update my beta installation?

Tags: updates, beta

I just installed the 12.04 beta1. When I start the update manager it detects more than 500 packages to be updated, 25 to be added and 6 to be removed.

I wonder if I will get a more stable system with these in "beta development" updates or if I should wait for beta2?

Answer (score 4):

Depends on what you expect from the beta.

If you are assisting with development or bug reports, you will want to update daily.

If you are expecting "stability" from the beta, you need to "do your homework" before upgrading. This includes looking at launchpad for recent bug reports, reading any release notes (when the beta 2 , alpha, etc are released), and checking http://ubuntuforums.org/forumdisplay.php?f=412

If you unwilling to tolerate bugs or even perhaps a broken system, don't run the beta.

Comment: Definitely check UbuntuForums before you do an update. This is even more important if you're joining at alpha level where things can be really, really broken (not to say that doesn't occasionally happen in betas too).

Answer (score 2):

I'm using the beta 1 right now and i recommend it, i see no limitations. And yes, there are more updates coming regularly but its fine.

Answer (score 1):

If its saying something like partial upgrade , then DONT go for it . else you can for upgrading when updates are offered by your update manager .

Comment: Any reason why a partial upgrade would do anything wrong? These are fine in the development version.

Comment: yeah please read this ,http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1859240

Comment: Oh, that's right. I must have confused partial upgrade with dist-upgrade.